# Do argon have a high energy?

Tags: energy, noble-gases

Do argon have a large energy density? And what level is it on? Is it weak or have a density like gasoline. How much energy can argon store and what noble gas have the highest energy density?

Comment: Argon is hardly a palatable substitute for gasoline.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of chemical reactions, Argon is not useful a fuel, as it doesn't react easily with any other elements - that's why it's called a [noble gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas).  [Compounds with Argon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon#Compounds) are very rarely seen.

Gasoline is a mixture of compounds of carbon and hydrogen.  These react easily with other chemicals, particularly oxygen, and these reactions allow it to be used as a fuel.

So Argon is useless as a conventional chemical fuel because it hardly reacts with any elements.